# 301 redirection - Trailing Slash web.config

Tags: asp.net, redirect, web.config-transform

I want to do permanent 301 redirect from **http://www.example.com/** to **http://www.example.com**.

I had tried below code in web.config, but not working.
Is there anything other changes I have to do?

```
<rule name="SEO - Remove trailing slash" stopProcessing="false">
         <match url="(.*)/$" />
         <conditions>
           <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
           <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
         </conditions>
         <action type="Redirect" url="{R:1}" />
       </rule>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to redirect the root domain, read this

http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.co.il/2010/04/to-slash-or-not-to-slash.html